# How to launch Main Window in Visit (Visualiser) using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python script that automatically draws out some plots and scatters on visit using my CFD results. I have the .visit file and it all works fine when I do it manually but I would like a python script to do it so I don't have to set everything up every time.
This is the code I wrote:

```
variable = ('nvrh','nvpr','nvtp')           # define variables
OpenDatabase("runs/movie.visit")            # open the data

for x in variable:
    print "Drawing variable : ", x
    AddPlot("Pseudocolor", x)
    p = PseudocolorAttributes()
    #p.colorTableName = "caleblack"
    #SetPlotOptions(p)
    DrawPlots()
```

and I run it on the terminal as:

```
visit -cli -s draw.py
```

which works just fine, but, the problem is it only creates a window and it fails to create the main window that you get when you normally launch visit. So i tried to launch it normally then add plots like so:

```
Launch()
variable = ('nvrh','nvpr','nvtp')
OpenDatabase("../runs/run2/movie.visit")
```

however when I do this, it launches an instant of visit then ignores the subsequent code and only when I close visit it does the same thing as before and launches only a single window.

What I am wondering is if there is a way of launching just the Main Window (the small menu thing) by the Python script.

Sorry if my question is a bit confusing and I am praying for experienced visit users as the community seems to be non-existent. Thanks for the help!